# PS: Create a multidimensional array from a text file - Cisco Switch Config

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a script to process multiple cisco configs and port them to Excel via CSV with the following fields: Interface Name, Description, VLAN and Voice VLAN.

I can import the config file with the following code:

```
$importPath = ["PATH TO FILE"]
$text = Get-Content -path $importFile
```

I can then process the imported text to group interfaces together like this:

```
$regex = '(?ms)interface(.+?)!'
$text = $text -join "`n"
$matchedGroups = $text | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

The resultant text is now in groups by interface (there is some junk in there, but it is minimal and manageable). However, I don't know how to then take these groups (lines of strings) and organize them in an array where each line is an element in the array. Once I have this, I can assign labels to sanitized and extracted information (as above). Example of text in the $matchedGroups variable:

```
PS: C:\$matchedGroups[0]
interface Port-channel1
 description Port-channel1 to DEVICE
 switchport access vlan ####
 switchport trunk native vlan ####
 switchport mode trunk
```

Desired array example:

```
$array = @("interface Port-channel1"," description Port-channel1 to DEVICE"," switchport access vlan ####"," switchport trunk native vlan ####"," switchport mode trunk")
```

Comment: have you try $array =$matchedGroups[0] -split "`n"    ?

Comment: @Esperento57 Yes. It gives the same output as just $matchedGroups[0]

Comment: @McKenning That's because PowerShell prints each string on a new line, it's indistinguisable from a multi-line string. Try: `$array = $matchedGroups[0] -split '\r?\n'; $array.Count`

Comment: For verify my proposition try to print first element array[0]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen With that command I get the same ouput as above, but wtih a "0" on a new line below it.

Comment: @Esperento57. Yes, they are different elements in the array! Let me verify with the rest of the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$array =$matchedGroups[0] -split "`n"

#print first element
$array[0]
```

If you want trim your rows :

```
$array=$string -split "`n" |%{$_.trim()}
```